# C# Problem - convert DateTime to Currency

Tags: c#, compilation, codeblocks

I am trying to convert a DateTime value on a timer to a $ value, see: currency.

I assume I would need to use a decimal in the middle.

At the moment, my code reads:

```
decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
dec = dec / 60 / 60 / 24 * X //where X = currency value.
label1.Text = String.Format("Order Total: {0:C}", dec);
```

Can anybody please offer assistance?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  How can the format `"hh:mm:ss"` represent a decimal?

Comment: what is the X datatype ?

Comment: Time is money..